# on click funtion in combo box using Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I created a combo box using extjs which is placed in the toolbar. I want to get grid table when I select any list in the combo box.
consider this example.

> I am having 3 values in my combo box
>
> ```
> 1,car
> 2,bike
> 3,train
> ```

In this combo box if I select car, then I need to get the grid Table below.
I tried some codes but its waste. Anyone please share me with small example and tell me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [down](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-down) and up to get other components.
Following is my example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28af

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if i select one list in drop down only that shoud display...again if i select next list only that should display

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

1. Let the parent (say panel) container contain the toolbar (with combobox) and three grids.
2. Give this container the `card` layout.
3. Handle the `select` event of combobox to set the `activeItem` property of the container equal to the selected item.

   ```
     Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
       layout: 'card',
       tbar: [{
           xtype: 'combo',
           fieldLabel: 'Select: ',
           value: 'Car',
           displayField: 'name',
           queryMode: 'local',
           store: {
               type: 'combo'
           },
           listeners: {
               select: function (combo, record) {
                   var val = record.get('value');
                   combo.up('panel').getLayout().setActiveItem(val)
               }
           }
       }],
       items: [{
           xtype: 'cargrid',
           activeItem: true
       }, {
           xtype: 'bikegrid',
       }, {
           xtype: 'traingrid',
       }],
       renderTo: Ext.getBody()
   });
   ```

   Here's a simple working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28b6). Please note that this example can be simplified with one grid class definition.

**Update:** If it's version 5.x or above then you can do it with binding. Refer to [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ik) example.